# Getting instance variable in scope of 'wp_enqueue_scripts'

Tags: theme-development, hooks, actions

I need a little help getting my head around passing instance variable to a hook.

I am reading the CSS files I need in my template dynamically and storing them in a `$settings` object that I am keeping inside the scope of my plugin namespace.

So I want to do something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts',function() {
    \mynamespace\ScriptQueuer::QueueCss($settings->GetCss());
} );
```

but obviously I need to pass the `$settings->GetCss()` return value into the scope somehow.

Do I make my `$settings` object global somehow?  I am not sure how to do that and also not sure its the best approach.  Is there anyway to achieve this or do I have to have all the CSS files hardcoded in a static function?

Comment: Have you tried `function() use ( $settings ) {`?

Comment: That has worked, the code is now firing but it has thrown a load of errors elsewhere which I am going through now.  Is it bad practice to queue scipts with anonymous function?  I just read elsewhere this is not a good thing to do as you cannot remove the script or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to solve this is to simplify your code. Right now, `ScriptQueuer::QueueCss()` is just a static method, and it is getting its data too late.

You could use an immutable object instead and then just register one of its methods as callback.

Example:

```
class Enqueuer {

    private $stylesheets;

    public function __construct( ArrayObject $stylesheets ) {

        $this->stylesheets = $stylesheets;
    }

    public function enqueue() {

        foreach ( $this->stylesheets as $stylesheet )
            wp_enqueue_script(
                $stylesheet->handle(),
                $stylesheet->url(),
                $stylesheet->dependencies(),
                $stylesheet->version(),
                $stylesheet->in_footer()
            );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', [
    new Enqueuer( $settings->GetCss() ),
    'enqueue'
] );
```

No need to pass data to the enqueue method, no need for a closure, and the code is easy to read.

Comment: This is much better.  Thanks, going to refactor along these lines.

Comment: Hahaaa, loving the [] construct! Took me like a full minute to understand.